# Не выводится контент в console.log через запятую

Tags: javascript

Не выводится переменная i в console.log через запятую

```js
const maxFirstTask = 20;
for (let i = 10; i <= maxFirstTask; i++) {
    console.log(i.join());
}
```

Comment: А почему он должен через запятую выводиться при текущем коде??

Comment: я предполагал при добавление .join() будет выводиться

Comment: Почему ты так предпологал?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Отлично. Ты увидел метод **для массивов** и решил применить к целым числам. Не смущает этот момент?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский подскажите а как можно сделать так чтобы выводилось через запятую

Comment: Ну в данном случае можно просто `console.log(i + ', ');` ....... в конце запятая правда останется, но тем не менее это самый простой способ

Comment: Можно на каждой итерации каждый элемент складывать в массив. А уже **после цикла** применить этот самый join к массиву

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский можете написать как это реализовать если вас не затруднит

Comment: @DmitriyYaroshchuk этому вы должны научиться сами, если за вам будут выполнять задачи, то вы соответственно не сможете выполнять их самостоятельно. Это приведёт вас к тому что базовые задачи вы не сможете решать сами. Поищите информацию о том что это за метод `join`, к чему он применяется и т.п.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Такой вариант с `join()` подойдет?

```
const maxFirstTask = 20;
const a = []
for (let i = 10; i <= maxFirstTask; i++) {
    a.push(i)
}
console.log(a.join(', '));
```

Но тут так же много чего нет если сравнить с примером ТС...

Comment: Если вас смущает вопрос тс'а, то тогда ознакомьтесь с текстом который ниже этого заголовка: `Отвечайте на хорошо заданные вопросы`. (Ссылка в комментариях, в вашем прошлом ответе)

Comment: Вам эти минусы, как повод задуматься об удалении ответов или их исправлении. Добавить комментраии в код с пояснением действий - 3 минуты. Я на первых парах тоже успел нахватать, потом пересмотрел подход к ответам